Change Tracking only sending Primary key on delete to Azure sqlTrigger function?
I'm having an issue finding a solution for a problem I'm having with the Change tracking feature in sql server. I have a SqlTrigger function app and I want to receive the bindings for the entire row that is deleted from a specific table.  Currently my function picking up the primary key when deleting a record.  It is my understanding this is a limitation of Change tracking for deleting. Is there a way to change/work around that?
I've also looked into using CDC (Change Data Capture),but I'm not having any luck with the function picking up any changes.  Is it possible for SqlTrigger function to work with CDC natively, or am I stuck with Change tracking?
Thanks!

Well, change tracking can never return the data being changed, so whatever your solution to this is, it won't be CT, you could log the deleted data somewhere though and join it later
